# XML System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, xml

When I tried to save Xml file to a specific folder, in the first saved is good because there's no existing xml file inside of it, but if I will save it again in the same folder same name the error will show ...

this is my example code to generate the xml file ....

```
 XMLPath = Path.Combine(TargetRFIFolder, filename);

                try
                {
                    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(XMLPath);

                    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("TeklaPartObject");

                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lv_Tekla_object.Items)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("part");
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("ID", item.Text);
                        xmlWriter.WriteString(item.SubItems[1].Text);
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("label");
                    xmlWriter.WriteString(Path.GetFileName(lv_Directories.SelectedItems[0].ToolTipText));
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                    xmlWriter.Close();
                    xmlWriter.Flush();
                    File.SetAttributes(XMLPath, File.GetAttributes(XMLPath) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

thanks for the help guys, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access to hidden file.
First remove the attribute as follows

```
File.SetAttributes(XMLPath, File.GetAttributes(XMLPath) & ~FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Then you can save it again in the same folder with the same name.
Then you can set hidden attribute again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stream and use it in your `XmlWriter`. The next program illustrates this. It creates an XML file (test.xml) twice. The second time it overwrites the already existing file.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace StackoverflowXmlFilesConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteXml("test.xml");
            WriteXml("test.xml");
        }

        static void WriteXml(string path)
        {
            using (var stream  = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    // replace this code with your XML writing code.
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Test");
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```